# Check if all chars match?

Tags: java

Basically, I have to write a method that determines whether all the characters in a string are the same, using only library String methods.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Nice, withhold answers for better written questions!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The string contains only repetition of 1 character?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, only repitition of 1 char

Comment: Note that you have [`charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) and [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) functions in the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class. Also note that the link aren't just for decoration purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aaaaa";

        int count = str.length() - str.replaceAll(String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)), "").length();
        if(count == str.length())
            System.out.println("All characters in a given String are same");
}
```

Try this : This is the simplest and best solution for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). Please read up the documentation of [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) class to understand how to use `matches` function to check your input. It is quite useless for me to give you a straight answer, since you don't learn much from it.

That method will give you one-liner solution after you have understood regex.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is without looping or recursion is by [ab]using [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace)<sup>1</sup>.

The actual implementation is left  as an exercise.

---

<sup>1</sup> It does not require that your code loops, but *something* must loop.